# How to check if a leaflet layer is already added on the map?

Tags: leaflet

I built a simple map app where I have a layer on top of a map. In Leaflet, how can I check if the layer is already present?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is a `hasLayer` method provided by Leaflet. It's a `Boolean` that returns true if already on the map.

For example, `map.hasLayer(yourUserDefinedLayerNameGoesHere);` will return `true` if it is added to the map or `false` if not.

For more details search the Leaflet documentation for `hasLayer` at: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-methods-for-layers-and-controls

Comment: You need to pass through a _reference to the Layer object_, not the _name of the layer_. The variable name in this example is ambiguous around this. Just wanted to clear it up for everyone else ;)