# leaflet esri identify features

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

I have layer(lote_ocupa) in control layers, when i launch application is disable but:

When I click on the map, even if the "lote_ocupa" layer is disabled, the identify function selects the feature, but that is wrong.

here is the part of the code:

```
var identifiedFeature;


mymap.on('click', function (e) {
    if(identifiedFeature){
      mymap.removeLayer(identifiedFeature);

    }
    lote_ocupa.identify().on(mymap).at(e.latlng).run(function(error, featureCollection){

      identifiedFeature = new L.GeoJSON(featureCollection.features[0], {
        style: function(){
          return {
            color: '#5C7DB8',
            weight: 2
          };
        }
      }).addTo(mymap);

    });
  });
```

How do fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "disabled" you mean not visible, you need to tell the `click` function to exit if the layer isn't currently visible on the map. You can use [hasLayer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193711/how-to-check-if-a-leaflet-layer-is-already-added-on-the-map) for this.

Try something like this:

```
mymap.on('click', function (e) {
  if (!mymap.hasLayer(lote_ocupa)) {
    return;
  }
  .....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much.

When I do it as you have shown:

```
if (!mymap.hasLayer(lote_ocupa)) {
    return;
  }
```

It works in part, it does not really let me select the feature before enabling the layer, but after I enable that problem comes in, I select a feature and when I select another it keeps the previous selected and also when I select where there is no selection It does not remove the selection.

So I tried to do this below to correct:

```
mymap.on('click', function (e) {
  if (!mymap.hasLayer(lote_ocupa)) {
      return;
    }
    else if(identifiedFeature){
      mymap.removeLayer(identifiedFeature);

    }
    lote_ocupa.identify().on(mymap).at(e.latlng).run(function(error, featureCollection){
      identifiedFeature = new L.GeoJSON(featureCollection.features[0], {
        style: function(){
          return {
            color: '#5C7DB8',
            weight: 2
          };
        }
      }).addTo(mymap);          
    });
  });
```

now works fine !! thank you so much Stephen.